# Calling a function from an extended class

Tags: php, entity-framework, oop

I want to develop something like my own framework for further websites, there is an existent answered question about my queries but i would like someone to help me so there is

*frameworkclass.php*

```
class Framework{
  public function hello(){
  echo "Hello World!";
}
```

*anotherclass.php*

```
class New extends Framework{
  $hellomessage = self::hello(); 
}
```

Well I know that I have to type `parent::hello()` to call the hello function from Framework class but how can i do it without typing everytime `parent::`
I don't know maybe something like this `$Framework->anyfunction()`?

Another thing that I don't understand about oop is whats the difference about a `static` variable and `other types`, or between `public` `protected` or `private` functions ?
What is a framework auto load function and whats the difference about the caching system of a framework and a framework based on sessions ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't initialise a property with a method.

```
class Framework {
    public function hello() {
       return "Hello World!";
    }
}

class New extends Framework {
    public $hellomessage;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->hellomessage = parent::hello();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer but do i have to type all the time `parent::hello()` to call hello function from Framework, or how can i do something like this $Framework->hello() ?

Comment: Declare `public static function hello()` and use `Framework::hello()`

Answer (score 0):

Public means the variable or function can be accessed from anywhere outside of the class.

Protected means the variable or function is only available to the class, and its child classes ( the classes that 'extend' it).

Private means the variable or function is only available to the class itself, and not even the child classes that extend it.

I  hope this is helpful.